# How to get a byte array out of a .bmp file? (winapi\assembler)

Tags: arrays, winapi, assembly

I simply need to print a .bmp file on a printer. In order to do that, i use "WritePrinter" function from winapi. The thing is - it reads a byte array of an image. So, how do i get a byte array from an image using winapi OR using pure assembler?
Thanks!

Comment: You do not need *a* byte array (which would be trivial to get, because that's what any file I/O will give you anyway). You need a byte array that follows a specific *protocol*. You cannot just dump any data. Sounds like you have oversimplified the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Well, maybe you are right, though i can't find any information about it on [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/writeprinter). How do i get ' a byte array that follows a specific protocol' than? And which protocol shold it follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how do i get a byte array from an image using winapi OR using pure assembler?

Unlike Linux, Windows does not (officially) allow any actions of a program but calls to the WinAPI.

It does not matter if you write your program in C or in assembly language.

So you have to use the WinAPI the same way you would use it in a C program.

> I simply need to print a .bmp file on a printer. In order to do that, i use "WritePrinter" function from winapi.

Using `WritePrinter` you can write:

- "Raw" data; this means: Data which is only understood by a certain printer model
- Plain text (this is what you can create using the "text editor" (notepad.exe))
- EMF data (a certain graphics format)

It seems not to be possible to send pixel image data using `WritePrinter`.

... unless you convert the pixel image to the data which is understood by exactly your printer model (which requires you to have internal information about your printer).

However, instead of the following set of APIs:

- `OpenPrinter`
- `StartDocPrinter`
- `StartPagePrinter`
- `WritePrinter`
- `EndPagePrinter`
- `EndDocPrinter`
- `ClosePrinter`

... you might want to use the following set of APIs:

- `CreateDC`
- `StartDoc`
- `StartPage`
- GDI graphics WinAPI functions
- `EndPage`
- `EndDoc`
- `DeleteDC`

These API functions allow you to draw on the printer using GDI graphics WinAPI functions (like `LineTo`, `FillRect`, `Ellipse`, `SetDIBitsToDevice` ...) that you would use to draw graphics on the screen.

You may then use the `SetDIBitsToDevice` function to print an image.

This function requires a pointer to the `BITMAPINFO` structure (`lpbmi`) which is located at offset 14 (0xE) of a .BMP file.

The word stored at offset 10 (0xA) of a .BMP file is the offset of the image data (`lpvBits`) into the .BMP file.

So you need to load the .BMP file into memory at some address "X" (e.g. by using `CreateFile`, `ReadFile` and `CloseHandle` APIs).

You read the 32-bit word "Y" stored at the address "X+0xA".

You pass the value "X+0xE" as `lpbmi` parameter and the value "X+Y" as `lpvBits` parameter to the `SetDIBitsToDevice` function.

Comment: Wow, man, thank you!